# transition of all arc path in d3.js using arcTween

Tags: d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I want to know how to use arcTween for animating for multiple arc path at a time.
And what exactly the use of interpolate.?

Please find the below image which i am trying to achieve but couldn't able to. I hope i will get a better solution here.[image]

And this is my code [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rajagopal/jvmcssc7/1/).

```
 var partition=d3.layout.partition()
                           .size([Math.PI/2, radius])
                           .value(function (d) { return d.depth; });
```

After every click on button the arc paths should change their path in the mean of transitioning or animating just like showed in the above image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312943/d3-sunburst-transition-given-updated-data-trying-to-animate-not-snap

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: Thanks for the link. I have tried this one, but i feel my requirements is quite different from it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I mean when ever i clicked on the button at that time all the sub arc path should go for transition and here in that example i am little bit confused. Here they will do the transition based on the path which we clicked on it. How can get only sub arc paths and do the transition?