# D3 sunburst with updated data: multiple transitions still snap, not smooth

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

This question builds on Lars Kotthoff's very helpful answer to the problem of transitioning with a D3 sunburst diagram that is based on different JSON data: [d3 - sunburst - transition given updated data -- trying to animate, not snap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312943/d3-sunburst-transition-given-updated-data-trying-to-animate-not-snap)

I've tried [the final fiddle that Lars provided](http://jsfiddle.net/jTV2y/3/) but when there is more than one transition, the animation still fails and we get snapping. The problem can be seen in [this updated fiddle that contains a second transition](http://jsfiddle.net/jTV2y/41/).

From what I can tell, the `x0` and `dx0` values are not properly stored with the path object when calling the `arcTweenUpdate` function. When I check what the `this` object looks like inside `arcTweenUpdate` function, I get an [object SVGPathElement] at the beginning of the function when `this.x0` and `this.dx0` are read, and I get an [object Window] when the new values are written later. I'm relatively inexperienced with JS but that seemed like it could point to the problem.

Any help with addressing this and making the above fiddle work for multiple transitions (e.g. back and forth between the two JSONs) is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you've spotted a bug in my earlier answer :)

The problem is, as you say, that the saved values aren't updated properly. That's because `this` inside the callback doesn't refer to the `path` DOM element anymore. The fix is simple -- save a reference to `this` in the function at the level above and use that reference:

```
function arcTweenUpdate(a) {
  var i = d3.interpolate({x: this.x0, dx: this.dx0}, a);
  var that = this;
  return function(t) {
    var b = i(t);
    that.x0 = b.x;
    that.dx0 = b.dx;
    return arc(b);
  };
}
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jTV2y/42/).