# d3.js - Reload chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have a d3 sunburst chart - based on this example:

https://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426

I've added a condition to control `d.depth` however as this changes, I need the chart to be refreshed with the new d.depth value.

```
var nodes = partition.nodes(json)
          .filter(function(d) {
          return (d.dx > 0.005 && d.depth < $scope.detailLevelForChart); 
});
```

Is there a simple `refresh()` method built in or do i have do something like remove the div and redraw the same way as when the page loads?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For sunburst charts you can found some examples of update by transition instead of remove and redraw all the graph.

Mike Bostock's Zoomable Sunburst example

https://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/477c1bfb081b783f80ad

Other link can be helpful

[d3 - sunburst - transition given updated data -- trying to animate, not snap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312943/d3-sunburst-transition-given-updated-data-trying-to-animate-not-snap)